# Programmatically Creating UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I know this should be very simple, but I've been really struggling with creating a UILabel programmatically and getting it to behave the way I would like.

All I want is to be able to create a label, set the maximum attributes as far as height, width and font size, and then have the text get smaller AND/OR just truncate the text to accommodate long strings of text.

Let's say that I want my label to have text that has a maximum width of 380, a maximum height of 20 and a maximum font size of 12.

So here is what I have attempted to do to create such a label:

```
UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, 0, 0)];
fromLabel.text = [self fromSender];
fromLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:ProximaNovaSemibold size:12]; //custom font
fromLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
fromLabel.baselineAdjustment = YES;
fromLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.size = [fromLabel.text sizeWithFont:fromLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(380, 20) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
fromLabel.minimumScaleFactor = MIN_SCALE_FACTOR;
fromLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
fromLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[collapsedViewContainer addSubview:fromLabel];
```

Ok, so the label appears, but the text is larger than 12 and the height always comes out to be 21!? Even if I change the height and text size values to extreme sizes, this code creates a label of some fixed size that can't be adjusted. The only thing I can seem to make smaller is the width.

I must be over looking something basic, but I really can't figure out how to get my desired result, nor do I understand why I'm getting the behavior that I am getting.

Comment: What's your intended minimum font size?

Comment: minimum font size is 10, and MIN_SCALE_FACTOR = 10/12

Comment: Isn't size a readonly property ? You may want to use frame here.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Does the following work ?

```
UIFont * customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:ProximaNovaSemibold size:12]; //custom font
NSString * text = [self fromSender];

CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:customFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(380, 20) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
fromLabel.text = text;
fromLabel.font = customFont;
fromLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
fromLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
fromLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
fromLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
fromLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[collapsedViewContainer addSubview:fromLabel];
```

edit : I believe you may encounter a problem using both `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumScaleFactor`. The former states that you also needs to set a `minimumFontWidth` (otherwhise it may shrink to something quite unreadable according to my test), but this is deprecated and replaced by the later.

edit 2 : Nevermind, outdated documentation. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` needs `minimumScaleFactor`, just be sure no to pass it 0 as a minimumScaleFactor (integer division, 10/12 return 0).
Small change on the `baselineAdjustment` value too.

Comment: I would think it would, but using the above, the label doesn't even appear.

Comment: Try commenting out `adjutsFontSizeToFitWidth`

Comment: Got it. Change MIN_SCALE_FACTOR to 10.0f/12.0f

Comment: still doesn't appear in the view.  I tried commenting out all the "adjustsTo..." in my previous code, and I still have the same original issue.

Comment: could you break after the addSubview and check that both objects exist and log their frame ?

Comment: sure - your code yields the frame: (91 15; 0 0), and mine yields: (91 15; 105 21)

Comment: Could font be nil ? Try with `UIFont * customFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];` I would tend to believe either the font or the text is nil, if the size returned is (0,0). You may want to inspect each of this elements.

Comment: wait, I think we just figured this out at the same time, its the font. the system isn't using the custom font and rather than giving an error, its inputting helvetica size 17. thanks!

Comment: `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode` was deprecated in IOS 7.0

Comment: @Nerkatel Hi, I have added links to documentation in your answer. If you believe I have overstepped the boundary here, you can click rollback. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

```
UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
/*important--------- */lbl1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[lbl1 setFrame:position];
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
lbl1.text= @"TEST";
[self.view addSubview:lbl1];
```

Answer (score 7):

here is how to create UILabel Programmatically..

1) Write this in .h file of your project.

```
UILabel *label;
```

2) Write this in .m file of your project.

```
label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 50, 50)];//Set frame of label in your viewcontroller.
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];//Set background color of label.
[label setText:@"Label"];//Set text in label.
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];//Set text color in label.
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];//Set text alignment in label.
[label setBaselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];//Set line adjustment.
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];//Set linebreaking mode..
[label setNumberOfLines:1];//Set number of lines in label.
[label.layer setCornerRadius:25.0];//Set corner radius of label to change the shape.
[label.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];//Set border width of label.
[label setClipsToBounds:YES];//Set its to YES for Corner radius to work.
[label.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];//Set Border color.
[self.view addSubview:label];//Add it to the view of your choice.
```

Comment: I know this is old, but how do I place the frame on the bottom of the view, right above a UIToolBar?  I like for the width to auto expand depending on length of string, or resize font size if too long?

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 3:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 250,height: 50))
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = .white
label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
label.text = "This is a Label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 300, 50)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.text = @"Your Text";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In Swift -

var label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 20))
label.center = CGPointMake(50, 70)
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "message"
label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **swift**

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 50))
label.textAlignment = .left
label.text = "This is a Label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UILabel *mycoollabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 50, 50)];
mycoollabel.text=@"I am cool";

// for multiple lines,if text lenght is long use next line
mycoollabel.numberOfLines=0;
[self.View addSubView:mycoollabel];
```

Comment: This might solve the problem but you could really do with adding some explanation of how/why it works.