# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell - programmatically

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, uicollectionview

Basically, I am trying to obtain something similar to the result of this tutorial: http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

I am quite lost in getting it working as I would like... my goal is:

Changing the collectionViewCell's from the tutorial to custom cells, containing for example a UILabel...

what code would I need to change? I have tried changing code in the following lines (from AFTableViewCell.h) but haven't gotten it working...

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    if (!(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) return nil;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing= 100000.0f;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 22);
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.collectionView = [[AFIndexedCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.collectionView];


    return self;
   }
```

I would like to add, for example, the corresponding tableviewcell + collectionviewcell numbers on each label;

my idea was (excuse my poor knowledge of iOS... I am beginning):

changing the registerClass method for a custom cell:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
```

having the MyCustomCollectionViewCell code the following in its .h file:

```
@interface MyCustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *simpleLabel;
@end
```

and then, I thought I would only have to add the following to where, in the tutorial, the background for each UICollectionViewCell background was set (AFViewController.m):

```
  -(MyCustomCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *collectionViewArray = self.colorArray[collectionView.index];
    cell.backgroundColor = collectionViewArray[indexPath.item];
    cell.simpleLabel.text = @"hi";

    return cell;
  }
```

However, no label is displayed...  (just tried to make it display "hi" for ease of testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with help from this question: [Programmatically Creating UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813121/programmatically-creating-uilabel)

Custom CollectionViewClass not needed, just edited the following method in AFViewController.m:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSArray *collectionViewArray = self.colorArray[collectionView.index];
cell.backgroundColor = collectionViewArray[indexPath.item];

UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,22)];
fromLabel.text = @"hi";
fromLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
fromLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; // or UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters, or UIBaselineAdjustmentNone
fromLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
fromLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
fromLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
fromLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[cell addSubview:fromLabel];


return cell;
```

`}`