# UILabel text won't display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm having trouble in an iOS app I'm building with UILabels: despite initializing them the text I programmed won't show up and I'm at wits' end about what I should do.

For example, this is one of the app's screens in which I have this problem:

**Welcome.m**

```
@interface Welcome()

@end

@implementation Welcome

-(void) viewdidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
    [self.view addSubview: label];
    label.text = @"Benvinguts a la pràctica de iOS I";
    label.numberOfLines = 4;

}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Tutorial1" sender:self];
}


@end
```

Could you help me out in fixing this?

Comment: textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Comment: does `Welcome` `viewController` even load? put a breakpoint on `-viewdidLoad:` and check if your app flows into this method.

Comment: Could it be a issue with the Menu Bar (in iOS7) that show a "hidden" text?

Comment: @JSA986: it doesn't change anything: I get "label" on screen, which means that the label DOES load but, for some reason, it refuses to load the text it's got to contain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a textColor:

```
   UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
    [self.view addSubview: label];
    label.text = @"Benvinguts a la pràctica de iOS I";
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything: I get "label" on screen, which means that the label DOES load but, for some reason, it refuses to load the text it's got to contain.

Comment: @user3082271 Maybe it is because of your special characters in your string? Try using something like `label.text = @"Test";`

Comment: Sorry. That didn't do it either. And, besides, I use accented words in another screen of the app and it works.

Comment: @user3082271 have you tried looking here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813121/programmatically-creating-uilabel

Comment: Yeah. I've had a look but I don't see anything I've already tried before.

Comment: plz check complete code in viewDidload ,may be u are using text="";

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
[self.view addSubview: label];
label.text = @"Benvinguts a la pràctica de iOS I";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label SizeToFit];
```

You may use like this (label size manage by itself.)

Comment: Can you add some context to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Viewcontroller a child? I had the same problem in my code, it would display the box but not ant text. I found a solution by adding a scrollview or something of the sort and adding the label to that got it working.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
label.text = @"Benvinguts a la pràctica de iOS I";
label.numberOfLines = 4;
[self.view addSubview: label];
```

or maybe your label appears under the NavigationController. Try dropping below

```
 UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 140, 47)];
```

Comment: How will that make a difference?