# iOS: UILabel text won't load

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, self

The text that I assign to `UILabel`s doesn't load in most of the cases: When there's the need to programmatically reload it or rewrite it that's when it works but in the other cases it doesn't.

The UILabels have been created in the storyboard and are correctly linked.

Here I'll provide a simple example:

**welcome.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Welcome : UIViewController

@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel * label;

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * entrar;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * benvingut;


@end
```

**welcome.m**

```
#import "Welcome.h"

@interface Welcome()

@end

@implementation Welcome

-(void) viewdidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
    [self.view addSubview: label];
    self.label.text = @"Benvingut a la pràtica de iOS I";
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Tutorial1" sender:self];
}


@end
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT**

My labels are definitely up to something odd because I use a different system to load the text into them in one of the screens and it works yet in another it doesn't. I'll add their code to make it clearer.

**Colors.h**

```
@interface Colors : UIViewController

@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel * label;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField * color;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * enviar;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel * correct;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * correcte;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * capcalera;

@end
```

**Colors.m**

```
#import "Colors.h"

@interface Colors()
@end

@implementation Colors


-(void) viewdidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _capcalera = @" Introdueix el color que vols que es mostri.";
    self.label.text= self.capcalera;


    _correcte = @"";
    self.correct.text = self.correcte;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_color resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

In this case the labels don't initialize as I want them to yet, in this other...

**Riddle.h**

## import

```
@interface Riddle : UIViewController

@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel * label;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField * resposta;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * enviar;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel * lab;


@property (strong, atomic) NSString * etiqueta;
@property (strong, atomic) NSString * eti;

@end
```

**Riddle.m**

```
#import "Riddle.h"

@interface Riddle()

@end

@implementation Riddle

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _etiqueta = @" 1: Que es allò blanc que tenia Santiago?";
    self.label.text = self.etiqueta;

    _eti = @"";
    self.lab.text = self.eti;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
            action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [_resposta resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Here the labels load as I tell them to: it's odd that the "Colors" screen doesn't do the same when the coding is almost identical.

Maybe these examples can contribute to figuring out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel text won't display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591326/uilabel-text-wont-display)

Comment: `UILabel * label` remove this and add `self.label` at all place.

Comment: Yes, @ChinttuRoxeNRamani is essentially correct. I explain why in my answer.

Comment: Are you using Interface builder to create the interface or are you just using programmatic code?

Comment: Yep, I 2nd @AlessandroOrrù's sentiment... Totally possible user3082271 hasn't actually created any label in the interface corresponding to the IBOutlet. Could be one of two things -- user3082271 could be trying to fully create the label programmatically or could be trying to set one from the interface.

Comment: Just to sum up: if you don't want to use interface builder, then you should check my answer. Otherwise if you want to use Interface Builder, just check @LyndseyScott answer and make sure you hook all outlets.

Comment: @alessandro eh, still doesn't make sense to me to declare a whole new label in your answer. I would do self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init ... Then self.text = ... etc. instead of setting self.label = label at the end.

Comment: @LyndseyScott It's just a reference, the allocated UILabel would be just one, so no performance impact. From a pure coding style perspective, your approach is absolutely cleaner (I would use it in my code), but I thought that for an answer my approach would have been more clear for the user.

Comment: Woah... is it just a typo of the question or your `viewDidLoad` method is really called `viewdidLoad`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just a typo of the question or your `viewDidLoad` method is really called `viewdidLoad` ? Case matters ;)

Comment: That might be it, even! I'll try out later. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: That was it indeed: what a stupid mistake, truly, but the auto-completion sometimes plays tricks on you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it seems like you're creating two separate labels: One in your interface, and one programmatically.

In fact, if the new `label` you're creating in your `viewDidLoad` has the same frame as your `self.label` IBOutlet, these lines are creating a new label which covers up your old one entirely:

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
[self.view addSubview: label];
```

Since you've already created the `UILabel` in your interface, there's no need to recreate it programmatically. You can remove the above lines entirely and access/set your pre-made IBOutlet label using `self.label`.

Replace all your code after `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `viewDidLoad` with:

```
self.label.text = @"Benvingut a la pràtica de iOS I";
self.label.numberOfLines = 4;
self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Edit: As per Alessandro Orrù suggestion, if you're not in fact creating the label in your interface (although your use of IBOutlet implies this), you may also set your UILabel programmatically by replacing all your code after `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `viewDidLoad` with:

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
self.label.text = @"Benvingut a la pràtica de iOS I";
self.label.numberOfLines = 4;
self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview: self.label];
```

P.S. If you've created a label in your interface, but it isn't hooked up properly, this 2nd solution will technically work, but your original interface label will be wasted; so I'd suggest learning how to hook up your `IBOutlet` properly.

Comment: I've done as you say but the text won't show up despite this: have I missed some step?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that you're not hooking up your view to your interface properly. Is there a label in your interface?

Comment: I up vote your answer since you have covered all cases now ;) nice job

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù ...I think I'm spending way too much time on this site. Time to go obsess over something else.

Comment: @LyndseyScott: there is a label in my storyboard, yeah. And it's properly linked, too.

Comment: @user3082271 (1) So when you select your label in the Storyboard and click the right-most button in the right panel next to the interface screen, "label ----- xFile's Owner" shows up underneath referencing outlets? (2) Could you post your new code underneath your original question in an edit?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the text to the IBOutlet reference `self.label.text = ...`, but you created a new UILabel instance, with no text assigned.

Try with:

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
[self.view addSubview: label];
label.text = @"Benvingut a la pràtica de iOS I"; // <<-- Removed 'self.'
label.numberOfLines = 4;
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.label = label; // <--- Add this
```

Comment: This answer creates a whole new label unnecessarily. Since it's already created in the interface.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'm not sure if he is using IB or not: there are no evidences in his question. You can use IBOutlet declaration also if you write your code all programmatically.
Anyway, if he uses IBOutlet, you are absolutely right. I just tried to write less edits to his code as possible.

Comment: You can see he's using IB in his .h

Comment: Again, you can write IBOutlet and IBAction declaration in an all-programmatic code, without a single XIB or Storyboard. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: OK, then...correction: You can see he's trying to use IB in his .h

Answer (score 1):

When you create a UILabel property, you have to use that property when creating the UILabel. An example:

```
// interface - @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
    self.label.text = @"text goes here";
    // or [self.label setText:@"text goes here"];
}
```

Without property variable

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 47)];
    label.text = @"text goes here";
    // or [self.label setText:@"text goes here"];
}
```

just a wrap up: if you are going to create a property, make sure to use self.varName so that you don't leave it just sitting around all alone.