# Add UILabel to CollectionViewCells programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My application requires several `CollectionViews` thus I decided to create them all programmatically. I added a `UILabel` to each cell however the UILabel is added only to random `cell`s while the others do not show any labels.

If I scroll up and down the textLabels randomly disappear within certain cells and reappear on others. 
Here is a visual depiction of the problem

(Notice the labels disappearing while I scroll down)

[image]

I need all the cells to display the textLabels.

This is the code I am using:

**I** *The View Controller*

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   let frame =                  CGRect(x: 0 , y: 50 , width: 375 , height: 300)
   let layout =                 UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
   let collectionView =         UICollectionView(frame: frame , collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate =   self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(CustomCell.self))
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 250    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell =             collectionView.dequeueReusableCell( withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(CustomCell.self), for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.nameLabel.text =  "XYZ"
    return cell

}
```

**II** *The Custom Cell*

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

 var nameLabel:  UILabel!

override init(frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)

    nameLabel =                 UILabel(frame:   self.frame)
    nameLabel.textAlignment =  .left
    nameLabel.textColor =      .black
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .red
  }

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

  }
```

What is causing this unusual behaviour? Am I setting up my `collectionView` incorrectly?

Comment: func CollectionView(_ CollectionView: UICollectionView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { .  What is this? This is how you return the size for a UICollectionViewCell https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. I updated the code.

Comment: Creating a UILabel programmatically requires from you to set all the properties IB is doing for you, thus, please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813121/programmatically-creating-uilabel also, have you tried bringing the UILabel to the front ?
Second issue, looks like you a dequeue problem, try to set the label inside the awakeFromNib method.

Comment: @6994 you should be using constraints to setup label programmatically ,and avoid using frame.

Comment: @TusharSharma You are absolutely right. Frame should be avoided. I solved the problem by replacing it with bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong in this line `nameLabel = UILabel(frame: self.frame)`, actually you are giving same position as collection view cell's position (x and y coordinates), which is wrong. You need to give nameLabel's positions x=0 and y=0, then it will work fine. Define the nameLabel's frame as below:

```
var nameLabel:  UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)

override init(frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    nameLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
}
```

Output as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was a very careless mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dequeue issue since it happens during cell dequeue.

You should initialize the UILabel inside the [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib) method - this way **every time** a cell gets dequeued you will create the label you need.

Also, since you are creating a UILabel programmatically you should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813594/4260691), basically when you create a UILabel programmatically, you should set a few more values.

I'd also suggest to use [bringSubViewToFront](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront?language=objc) when creating the label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know how `awakeFromNib`  would be useful since I am not using `InterfaceBuilder` . Also I tried using `bringSubviewToFront` within the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method , but that didn't work either.

Comment: Just override awakeFromNib and refactor your code into awakeFromNib - it is good for both storyboard and nib. If you still insist, you can always create a setup method (refactor your UILabel code into it) inside the cell and invoke it after a dequeue inside cellForRow but it's a bad practice

Comment: I'm doing everything programatically thus there are neither storyboards nor nibs.

Comment: @6994, so create a method inside your cell, name it setupCell() and encapsulate the UILabel creation inside of it. Invoke this method after each cell dequeue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that every cell has a different `frame.origin` value therefore setting  `UILabel(frame : self.frame )` would be incorrect.

example:

```
   let label = UILabel(frame: self.frame)
   print(self.frame)                     // (130.0, 420.0, 50.0, 50.0)

 // the origin of the label is now CGPoint(130.0, 420.0) with respect to the 
 //cell it would be totally out of bounds somewhere down below.
```

The `origin` of each `UILabel` needs to be `CGPoint(x :0,y :0)` so that it appears right on top of its respective cell.

Therefore the simple solution was to replace frame with bounds.

```
   let label = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
```